# Sorting very large 1D arrays

Tags: numpy, pandas, pytables

I'm about to try out Pytables for the first time and I need to write my data to the hdf file  per time step. I'll have over 100,000 time steps. When I'm done, I would like to sort my 100,000+ x 6 array by column 2, i.e., I currently have everything sorted by time but now I need to sort the array by order of decreasing rain rates (col 2). I'm unsure how to even begin here. I know that having the entire array in memory is unwise. Any ideas how to doe this fast and efficiently?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: What's wrong with [`Table.readSorted()`](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.Table.readSorted) or [`Table.iterSorted()`](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.Table.itersorted)? And by the way, 100k rows with 6 fields each is not much, as long as your fields are numeric (about 5 MB).

Comment: I was not aware of these sorting functions. Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that having the entire array in memory is unwise.

You might be overthinking it. A 100K x 6 array of `float64` takes just ~5MB of RAM. On my computer, sorting such an array takes about 27ms:

```
In [37]: a = np.random.rand(100000, 6)

In [38]: %timeit a[a[:,1].argsort()]
10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a very old computer, you should put the entire array in memory. Assuming they are floats, it will only take `100000*6*4./2**20 = 2.29` Mb. Twice as much for doubles. You can use numpy's sort or argsort for sorting. For example, you can get the sorting indices from your second column:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(100000,6))
idx = a[:, 1].argsort()
```

And then use these to index the columns you want, or the whole array:

```
b = a[idx]
```

You can even use different types of sort and check their speed:

```
In [33]: %timeit idx = a[:, 1].argsort(kind='quicksort')
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit idx = a[:, 1].argsort(kind='mergesort')
100 loops, best of 3: 14.4 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit idx = a[:, 1].argsort(kind='heapsort')
10 loops, best of 3: 21.4 ms per loop
```

So you see that for an array of this size it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have under-estimated the array size. I have done this in numpy before the time index was over 330 million. I forgot to multiply it by the lat and lone. Also the size will increase as I process data with higher and higher horizontal resolution. Appreciate the tip. I'm in the process of writing the code and adapting my old numpy scripts.